# Reactions in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I just updated my djs bot from v11 to v12, and all commands are working, but one isn't. I have a vote command, if I type !vote 3, it reacts with 1,2,3. And it gives me back nothing. It deletes my message, but, it doesn't react and doesn't send the embed. In v11 it worked fine.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'vote',
    description: 'Szavazás létrehozása',
    guildOnly: true,
    dmOnly: false,
    adminOnly: false,
    execute(message, args) {
        const channel = message.channel;
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.send("Adj meg egy paramétert!");
        } else {

        const parameter = parseInt(args[0], 10);
        if (parameter > 10 || parameter < 0) {
            message.channel.send("Adj meg egy 0 és 10 közötti számot!");
            return;
        }
        message.delete({ timeout: 1 })
        .then (() => channel.fetchMessages({ limit: 1 }).then(messages => {
            let lastMessage = messages.first();
            if (lastMessage.member != message.member) {
                message.channel.send("Nem tőled származik az előző üzenet.");
            }
            
          
            if (!lastMessage.author.bot) {
                if (args[0] === "0") {
                    lastMessage.react('✅')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('❎'));
                }
                if (args[0] === "1") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                }
                if (args[0] === "2") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "3") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "4") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "5") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "6") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "7") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "8") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "9") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('9️⃣'))
                }
                if (args[0] === "10") {
                    lastMessage.react('1️⃣')
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('2️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('3️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('4️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('5️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('6️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('7️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('8️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react('9️⃣'))
                    .then (() => lastMessage.react(''))
                }
                
            }
          }))
          .then(() => {
          const Discord = require('discord.js');
          const confirm = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setColor("GREEN")
          .setDescription("Szavazás létrehozva. Reagálj a megfelelő emojival a szavazáshoz!");
          message.channel.send({embed: confirm});
    }) ; }
}
}
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please don't use if chains that could be replaced with a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch). If you still are going to use this at least change it to if/elseif

Heres the issue: `message.channel.send({embed: confirm});`

Change it to `message.channel.send(confirm);`

Comment: I just changed all the if-s to switches and I changed the msg.channel.send too, and the bot sended the message, bot nothing react. This is interesting, because the embed send is **after** the reactions. I just logged every single steps into the console and it didn't log after the `.then(() => channel.fetchMessages...`

What is the problem? Can you help me? Thanks :)

(Answering to @Diamond)